# How to show network error message in react native

Tags: react-native, exception, fetch, throw

I have a react native function which uses the fetch function to post some data. The problem is I can't alert the response error message. My error code is 400. this is my code:

```
fetch(conf.getsignUpURL(), {
              method: "POST",
              headers: {
                  'Accept': 'application/json',
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              },
              body: JSON.stringify(data)
          })
              .then(function (response) {
                  if (!response.ok)
                  {
                     let error = new Error(response.statusText);
                      throw error;
                  }else
                  {
                      return response.json();
                  }

              })
              .then(async function (data) {
                  //something
              }).catch( (error) => {
              alert(error.message);
          });
```

After the run, it will alert empty.

Comment: just try alert(error) and see what you get ?

Comment: @Firu it only alert _Error_ .the problem is statusText is empty.

Answer (score -1):

```
fetch(conf.getsignUpURL(), {
              method: "POST",
              headers: {
                  'Accept': 'application/json',
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              },
              body: JSON.stringify(data)
          })
              .then(function (response) {

                // Here I added the alert
                alert(JSON.stringify(response))

                  if (!response.ok)
                  {
                     let error = new Error(response.statusText);
                      throw error;
                  }else
                  {
                      return response.json();
                  }

              })
              .then(async function (data) {

                // Here I added the alert
                alert(JSON.stringify(data))

                  //something
              }).catch( (error) => {
              alert(error.message);
          });
```